# Mysql replace string when needed query

Tags: mysql, string, replace

I have a table called: `k01cv_sh404sef_urls`
Inside this table we have the following rows:

```
id, cpt, rank, oldurl, newurl and dateadd
```

The row "oldurl" contains entry's such as:

```
English/network
English/hardware-and-software
corporate-social-responsibility
```

I'd like to have a query that removes the English/ part from all the items in the "oldurl" row so that the english/network would be just network, English/hardware-and-software would be hardware-and-software, etc.

The result would be that the row "oldurl" contains entry's such as:

```
network
hardware-and-software
corporate-social-responsibility
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you get away with something as simple as this?

```
UPDATE table SET oldurl = REPLACE(oldurl, 'English/', '');
```

(please test using a SELECT before running it on the real data!)

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE k01cv_sh404sef_urls
SET    oldurl = SUBSTRING(oldurl FROM 9)
WHERE  oldurl LIKE 'English/%'
```

This will not just read/attempt to update only matching records (which will yield a particular performance benefit if your table is large but has an index in which `oldurl` is the leftmost column), but will also only strip the `'English/'` that appears at the very start of the string.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly.

I also have some url's like
nl/nederlands/hardware-en-software

Where I want to remove the /nederlands/ part. How can I accomplish this?